# React Router Dom, difference between passing id as url params or state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

This is more of a poll than anything else.
When working with React, do you pass parameters when routing by chaining them to the `URL` or as `state`?

Is there even a best practice to follow for this?

Params:

```
navigate('/edit/${user.id}')`
```

State:

```
navigate('/edit', { state : {id :user.id} } )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what you prefer and what your project needs. The difference between the two is as follow:

1. `navigate('/edit', { state : {id :user.id} })` won't write the `id` in the `url`. And you consume it with the help of [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-location) hook, this way:

> ```
> import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
> function Edit() {
>  const { state } = useLocation();
>  return (
>   <div>
>      {state.id}
>    </div>
>  );
> }
> export default Edit;
> ```
>
> It's more flexible as you can or not pass the `id`. For example you can pass it when you are navigating from `login` page, but not in other cases.

2. `navigate('/edit/${user.id}')` would mean that you have defined a `slug` while setting up your route, like so:

> ```
> <Route path = "/edit/:id" element= {<Edit/>}/>
> ```
>
> And you consume it this time with [useParmas](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-params) hook:
>
> ```
> import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
> function Edit() {
>  const { id } = useParams();
>  return (
>   <div>
>      {id}
>    </div>
>  );
> }
> export default Edit;
> ```
>
> In the last case the `id` should be there, all the time, to make a correct `path`.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it depends on the action I am trying to do.

If I want a single route with some dynamic information, such as chat id, which I don't want to be stored in the URL, I prefer setting it in the history state.

But, for REST actions (edit/add and such on), I prefer chaining the `id` in the URL itself. It has some benefits. The primary one I see is that you can copy the URL, paste it somewhere else (different computer/browser), and you'll still access the same page with the details about the `id` you chained.