# What is the best solution to pass data between componenets in React

Tags: reactjs, components

This is my App.js:

```
    function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/creation" element={<Creation />} />
            <Route path="/payment" element={<Payment />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I need to pass a string generated in the "Creation page" to the "Payment page."

Meanwhile, once the string is generated on the creation page, the user should be automatically directed to the payment page. ( I have a solution for this: useNavigate( ) ).

Does anyone know what is the best solution to reach this goal?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Google it, there are plenty of demo tutorials out there

Comment: Might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72926862/react-router-dom-difference-between-passing-id-as-url-params-or-state.

Answer (score 0):

In [React Router v6](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/getting-started/overview) you can pass parameters to the url your navigating to

```js
navigate(`/payment/${yourString}`);
```

then in payments:

```js
import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
    
const params = useParams();
```

then you can access your string with `params.yourString`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But "no roots matched location" is the error I am given after heading to the payment page.

Comment: I must add logic to the <Routes> part of my script to let the payment page URL be followed by a custom string each time. Am i right?

Comment: To clarify more, I need to make my payment page URL append a string to its URL each time creation is successful. Also, at every scenario, the string is different

Comment: Your problem is not clear please supply more code examples