# React useParams - dynamic content

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'd like to use the id of useParams.

Anyone know how to do this? I did not find any solution in google :(

All the code in here.
I want to use id for every currency subpage. Now the default is USD and I want it to be dynamic And I would like the id to be here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2soZ.png

```
import axios from 'axios';
import CurrencyInput from 'components/atoms/CurrencyInput/CurrencyInput';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function CalculatorNew() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [amount1, setAmount1] = useState(1);
  const [amount2, setAmount2] = useState(1);
  const [currency1, setCurrency1] = useState('PLN');
  const [currency2, setCurrency2] = useState('USD');
  const [rates, setRates] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        'https://api.apilayer.com/fixer/latest?base=PLN&apikey='
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setRates(response.data.rates);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!!rates) {
      function init() {
        handleAmount1Change(1);
      }
      init();
    }
  }, [rates]);

  function format(number) {
    return number.toFixed(4);
  }

  function handleAmount1Change(amount1) {
    setAmount2(format((amount1 * rates[currency2]) / rates[currency1]));
    setAmount1(amount1);
  }

  function handleCurrency1Change(currency1) {
    setAmount2(format((amount1 * rates[currency2]) / rates[currency1]));
    setCurrency1(currency1);
  }

  function handleAmount2Change(amount2) {
    setAmount1(format((amount2 * rates[currency1]) / rates[currency2]));
    setAmount2(amount2);
  }

  function handleCurrency2Change(currency2) {
    setAmount1(format((amount2 * rates[currency1]) / rates[currency2]));
    setCurrency2(currency2);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Currency Converter</h1>
      <CurrencyInput
        onAmountChange={handleAmount1Change}
        onCurrencyChange={handleCurrency1Change}
        currencies={Object.keys(rates)}
        amount={amount1}
        currency={currency1}
      />
      <CurrencyInput
        onAmountChange={handleAmount2Change}
        onCurrencyChange={handleCurrency2Change}
        currencies={Object.keys(rates)}
        amount={amount2}
        currency={currency2}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default CalculatorNew;
```

Please help

Comment: Can you please show your Router code and give react-router-dom version since there is a big difference between pre 5 and 6+

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"

Comment: `return (
    <Router>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <GlobalStyle />
        <Wrapper>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Countries />}></Route>
            <Route path="/:id" element={<Currency />}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </Wrapper>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Router>
  );`

Comment: As it seems you have :id in for Curreny component but you are trying to get it with useParams in CalculatorNew

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Router Dom, difference between passing id as url params or state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72926862/react-router-dom-difference-between-passing-id-as-url-params-or-state)

Answer (score 0):

How did you register your Route in app.js?, Did you add the id params to the path?

```
  <Route path='/calculator/:id' element={< Currency />} />
```

What do you get when you console.log "id" in CalculatorNew component?

Then replace the value you want to change with the id. I edited my answer

```
          useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.apilayer.com/fixer/latest?base=${id}&apikey=1pCczTDZ8Do6rgsOls3UQxMvcQ2ZuAVS`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setRates(response.data.rates);
      });
  }, []);
```

You should also use environment variables for your apikey.

[https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-vanillajs/#:~:text=Environment%20variables%20store%20variables%2C%20as,create%20a%20new%20file%20called%20](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-vanillajs/#:%7E:text=Environment%20variables%20store%20variables%2C%20as,create%20a%20new%20file%20called%20).

Comment: No, the calculator is in the Currency component
<Route path = "/: id" element = {<Currency />}> </Route>

Comment: In the console I have the value of id

Comment: Then replace the value you want to change with the id. I edited  my answer

Comment: But when I change useState like this, it doesn't work
const [currency2, setCurrency2] = useState (id);

Comment: what about if you add setCurrency2(id) in the useEffect where you fetch your data?

Comment: Like that? Nothing `useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        'https://api.apilayer.com/fixer/latest?base=PLN&apikey=1pCczTDZ8Do6rgsOls3UQxMvcQ2ZuAVS'
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setRates(response.data.rates);
      });
    setCurrency2(id);
  }, []);`

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget that the ID you get from the params is a string initialy and not a number at first.

Comment: This can be added as a comment... I know you don't have enough reputation to comment but that you can achieve by asking good questions